# Investigating into Float16 training in TensorFlow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

TensorFlow slim pre-trained models are saved with their weights in `tf.float32`. For the purpose of memory efficiency, I would like to load a pre-trained model in `tf.float16` and then run some training operations after attaching a few other modules in `tf.float16`.

I am aware that doing this normally is not possible due to the tensor data type mismatch. However, is there a good resource dedicated to this issue ? 
Has anyone tried something like this before ?

For records, following is a snippet which I used just to verify if pretrained models can be restored in `tf.float16` and it did not work.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from inception_v4 import inception_v4, inception_v4_arg_scope
import numpy as np
slim = tf.contrib.slim
dtype = tf.float16
input = tf.placeholder(dtype, [None, 299,299,3])
with slim.arg_scope(inception_v4_arg_scope()):
    logits, endpoints = inception_v4(input)

saver = tf.train.Saver()

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

img = np.random.randn(10, 299, 299, 3)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    saver.restore(sess, './inception_v4.ckpt')
    l = sess.run(logits, feed_dict={input : img})
```

The output is

```
2018-06-26 21:14:51.708190: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1361, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _run_fn
    target_list, status, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 516, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected to restore a tensor of type half, got a tensor of type float instead: tensor_name = InceptionV4/AuxLogits/Aux_logits/biases
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_HALF, DT_HALF, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_HALF, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_HALF], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    saver.restore(sess, './inception_v4.ckpt')
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1755, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 905, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1137, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1355, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1374, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected to restore a tensor of type half, got a tensor of type float instead: tensor_name = InceptionV4/AuxLogits/Aux_logits/biases
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_HALF, DT_HALF, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_HALF, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_HALF], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]

Caused by op 'save/RestoreV2', defined at:
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1293, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1302, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1339, in _build
    build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 796, in _build_internal
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 449, in _AddRestoreOps
    restore_sequentially)
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 847, in bulk_restore
    return io_ops.restore_v2(filename_tensor, names, slices, dtypes)
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 1030, in restore_v2
    shape_and_slices=shape_and_slices, dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3271, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/meetukme/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1650, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected to restore a tensor of type half, got a tensor of type float instead: tensor_name = InceptionV4/AuxLogits/Aux_logits/biases
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_HALF, DT_HALF, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_HALF, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_HALF], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
```